# Get value of attribute in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div data-width="70"></div>
```

I want to set it's width in CSS equal to the value of data-width attribute, e.g. something like this:

```
div {
    width: [data-width];
}
```

I saw this was done somewhere, but I can't remember it. Thanks.

Comment: You can use this `var width = 70px;` then in the code you can write it as `width: @width // asp.net web pages variable`. It would be better to use the Style in the page's head not in a seperate file.

Comment: This was proposed as CSS3 `attr()` but not implemented. It cannot be achieved with CSS2 `attr()`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need [the `attr` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()):

```
div {
    width: attr(data-width);
}
```

The problem is that (as of 2021) it's not supported even by some of the major browsers (in my case Chrome):

> Note: The `attr()` function can be used with any CSS property, but
> support for properties other than [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) is experimental, and support
> for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.

Comment: But this is the correct answer. @amar you could mark it as the correct one, as you were the questioner.

Comment: so the answer was ```width: attr(data-width);``` ;)

Comment: except that it doesn't work, 2021 in Firefox: https://jsbin.com/magiweteno/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 13):

You cant pass data attribute value directly in to css without pseudo type content.
Rather you can do this way.. **[CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://goo.gl/T32qn2)**

```
<div data-width="a"></div><br>
<div data-width="b"></div><br>
<div data-width="c"></div>
```

CSS

```
div[data-width="a"] {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 10px;
    width:70px;
}
div[data-width="b"] {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 10px;
    width:80px;
}
div[data-width="c"] {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 10px;
    width:90px;
}
```

Comment: I can pass it, I saw it before.

Answer (score 13):

Inline [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are almost as declarative as data attributes, and they are [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) now, in contrast to the `attr()`. Check this out:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
var jsVar = elem.style.getPropertyValue("--my-var");
function next() {
  jsVar = jsVar % 5 + 1; // loop 1..5
  elem.style.setProperty("--my-var", jsVar);
}
```

```css
.d1 {
  width: calc( var(--my-var) * 100px );
  background-color: orange;
}
.d2 {
  column-count: var(--my-var);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="next()">Increase var</button>
<div id="demo" style="--my-var: 2">
  <div class="d1">CustomWidth</div>
  <div class="d2">custom columns number custom columns number custom columns number custom columns number custom columns number custom columns number custom columns number</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Another approach would be using [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) with style element to pass values from HTML to CSS.

```css
div {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
}
```

```html
<div
  style="
    --width: 50px;
    --height: 25px;
    --backgroundColor: #ccc;
  "
></div>

<div
  style="
    --width: 100px;
    --height: 50px;
    --backgroundColor: #aaa;
  "
></div>
```

Comment: You're a genius... The data-approach wasn't working for me, but this did, probably because i could literally set it to exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CSS is static styling information about specific html element and not the other way around. If you want to use CSS to set the width of your div I suggest you do with the use of classes:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    width: 70px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cuPk/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just having fun with this, but a jQuery solution would be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='foo' data-width='70'></div>
<div class='foo' data-width='110'></div>
<div class='foo' data-width='300'></div>
<div class='foo' data-width='200'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 0; /** defaults to zero **/
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foo').each(function(i) {
    var width = $(this).data('width');
    $(this).width(width);
  });
});
```

Codepen sketch here: http://cdpn.io/otdqB

---

**KIND OF AN UPDATE**
Not what you're looking for, since you want to pass a variable to the width property. You might as well use a class in this case.

**HTML**

```
<div data-width='70'>Blue</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div[data-width='70'] {
  width: 70px;
}
```

Sketch here: http://cdpn.io/jKDcH

Comment: I already have this done in jQuery, that's why I am asking for a way to do it in css.

Comment: @AmarSyla There is no way to do it in CSS

Answer (score 0):

`<div data-width="70"></div>`

use `attr()` to get the value of attribute;

```
div {
    width: attr(data-width);
}
```

Comment: This will be passed as a string and does not work.

Answer (score -3):

can you try this

```
 $(function(){
    $( "div" ).data( "data-width" ).each(function(this) {

        $(this).width($(this..data( "data-width" )))

    });
 });
```