# Use CSS to access style custom attribute

Tags: html, css

I don't know if this is possible or not, but any help would be very appreciated.

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<img src="mountains.jpeg" class="green inline-image" data-caption="A picture of mountains!">
```

where `data-caption` is a custom attribute.

I want to do something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjjHR.png).

As you can see, the `data-caption` has to be in a small box right under the image, with the exact width as the image. I don't know if this is possible or not, so can you recommend an alternative way if not?

I tried doing something like this:

```
<img src="mountains.jpeg" class="green inline-image">
<div class="photo-caption">
    A picture of mountains!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inline-image {
    width:30%;
}

.photo-caption {
    width:30%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

This works, but I'd prefer to not have to make a new `<div>` for every caption. I'd rather have it in the `<img>` tag.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300536/get-value-of-attribute-in-css

Comment: You can use JavaScript ;-)

Comment: You can do it if you use div with background image

Comment: Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/0gv5sv4q/ ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements

Comment: Why the heck you want to do it in a wrong way? If you do not want to make "another" div, create figure and caption instead. Web documents are meant to be semantic

Comment: @MaciejKwas can you please explain what you mean by "web documents are meant to be semantic"? I do not really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's possible using css `content` but problem in your case is you are using it on an `img` element which won't work on some [browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements).

A different approach I would suggest is to insert your `img` element inside a `div` and have that custom attribute in there.

**html:**

```
<div class="img-block" data-caption="A picture of mountains!">
  <img src="mountains.jpeg" class="green inline-image" >
</div>
```

**css**

```
.img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-caption);
}
```

[Reference](http://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr)