# Dynamically force the width of a div to equal its height

Tags: html, css

Here I am trying to make the width of a div be the same exact dimensions as its height so that it stays a perfect square. The height is a percentage of it's parent div, so there is no exact pixel value of it's height.

**How can I make a div perfectly square if I do not know the exact height in pixels?**

I have given a link below to demonstrate what I am saying. In the example I want the cyan colored div to dynamically transform it's width to match the dimensions of it's height so that it remains a perfect square. I would like to be able to do this in CSS code but if not, it's okay.

https://jsfiddle.net/5pdLpqrg/

CSS:

```
#parent{
  height: 70px;
  width: 450px;
  background: #999;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
#perfect_square{
  height: 78%;
  width: 80px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300536/get-value-of-attribute-in-css

Comment: The best way to do this would be using javascript. I tried doing this using css but was finally forced to use some javascript help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with javascript you can set an intervalthat checks every x seconds to change the width, I set the interval to check every 100ms.

```
interval = setInterval(function(){
    var square = document.getElementById('perfect_square');
    square.style.width = square.offsetHeight + "px";
},100);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good way for those of you using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **CSS-only** solution:

```css
#parent {
  width:350px;
  height:200px;
  background:silver; 
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
#container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
#perfect_square {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="container">
      <div id="dummy"></div>
      <div id="perfect_square">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another **CSS-only** solution:

```css
.parent {
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
  background:silver;
}

.perfect_square {
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background:cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="perfect_square"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you for the accept, I would appreciate an upvote there too :)

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even remember that :) sorry.

Comment: Nice Solution :) Liked it @FaustoNA

Comment: Very nice solution! One little tweak though: How can I make the width follow the height rather than the height follow the width. Like when I adjusted the parent height it did not effect the cyan div size, but when I adjusted the parent width, it did effect the cyan square. How can I do the opposite of this? I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: The second javascript answer by mangasaske worked perfect. But I would like to do it using only CSS. :)

Comment: I spent a while trying to achieve this (make the width follow the height rather than the height follow the width) with no success. I'll try again later :(

Comment: Yes thank you, if you could find a solution that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript for this.

```
var square = document.getElementById('perfect_square');
square.style.width = square.offsetHeight + "px";
```

Remove `perfect_square`'s `width` attribute in your CSS file and use the code above to dynamically set its width. Try it on JSFiddle.

Comment: When I resize the parent div the cyan div doesn't update it's width. I want the width to always be the same as the height.

Comment: mangasaske answer above is good. He basically just rerun the code i provided every 100ms.