# remove overriding css without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added an image with width and height attributes, but they got overriden by a css-class.
The class couldn't be changed, because it's from a library and I would destroy much of the styling. A solution would be setting the styling attributes, but i can't, because the image come from an editor (tinyMCE).

How can i invalidate the current two css attributes or override them with the image attributes without using jquery? Other solutions are also welcome.

thank you

html snippet from editor:

```
 <img src="https://crossbrowsertesting.com/design/images/cbt-sb_logo.svg" alt="" width="422" height="69">
```

styling from debugger:

```
md-card > img, md-card > :not(md-card-content) img {
box-sizing: border-box;    
display: -webkit-flex;    
display: -ms-flexbox;    
display: flex;    
-webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;    
-ms-flex: 0 0 auto;    
flex: 0 0 auto;    
width: 100%;    
height: auto;
}

img[Attributes Style] {    
width: 422px;    
height: 69px;
}
```

As mentioned i can't change the html snippet because it gets delivered from an
editor. Also the image size gets set dynamically

Comment: Please provide example HTML and CSS code to work with.

Comment: Use hierarchy and create new rule and set property values `!important`;

Comment: try !important on desired class

class{
property1:vlaue !important;
property2:vlaue !important;
property3:vlaue !important;
}

Comment: is there a way to set !important to the img attributes?
I discoverd this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300536/get-value-of-attribute-in-css
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your image comes in as

```
<img src="/imgs/test.png" class="imgTest" alt="img"/>
```

Then in you own .CSS file you can give it a property of !important, like so.

```
.imgTest 
{
   width: 20px !important;
   height: 30px !important;
}
```

Answer(pseudocode):
Use Javascript for the solution

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = "10px";
    x[i].style.height = "10px";
  }
```

[jsfiddle.net/0yfxpqwz](http://jsfiddle.net/0yfxpqwz)

Comment: the width and height get set dynamically by the user with the editor. Otherwise your solution would work with hierarchy

Comment: and you are sure you don't want to use javascript or jquery?

Comment: Maybe the only solution is javascript...jquery isn't a solution because angular and jquery are two different paradigma.

something like (pseudocode):
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
img.style = 'width:' + img.width;

should work.

Comment: Yeah, but then you are resizing every img-tag on your page, you should get the element by Id og Class if possible. https://jsfiddle.net/0yfxpqwz/

Comment: Also update the answer so person who come may notice your solution as well

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to include a external css right after the predefined css library so that your css will have more preference over predefined css. i.e:

```
<link href="css/predefined.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/your.css" rel="stylesheet">
```